# Is it possible to change maximum battery capacity to a lower value?

Tags: charging, battery-life

AccuBattery says my phones battery health capacity is around 80-90%. Android and all other devices naturally keeps charging to 100%, even though it will only be 90% charged. To me, this seems to be the reason some capacity ranges might be unstable and the phone quickly die when it reaches 15%, because it tries to stretch the capacity without knowing it is doing it. So the question is, is there any simple apps to just replace or use a different battery percent viewer, or some other options, that lets me set the maximum capacity to the health of the battery? So in that way it will be as stable as it was when it was new, still charge to max, but rather spread the 90% health on 90% capacity and then dont have any sudden drops and unstable battery life.
Prefered non-root options or any launchers with these options, but if there exists a root-way i would love to know it

Comment: If your device is rooted the chance is high that you can use an app that stops charging when a certain level is reached e.g. [Battery Charge Limit](https://github.com/sriharshaarangi/BatteryChargeLimit). Alternatively on non-rooted devices you can use an app that notifies you when the specified battery level is reached so that you can disconnect the device from charger.

Comment: Its not about stopping charging, but changing the max value from 100% to the realistic 90% and make it therefore more normal when decharging

Comment: The battery charging uses a special controller chip which determines how full a battery is based on the charging current. That is like a self-learning system as the max battery capacity can change at any time because the battery gets weaker. Not sure if it is possible even with root permissions to modify the charging process.

Comment: Thats true and might cause big problems. Unless you can modify the code of the chip to say the max is the battery health left, you could make a program that simply divided health by 100% capacity, then multiplied with what should be left in the original. So with 80% health, having 50% would be instead 80/100*50 would give 40%. It may be inacurate and maybe not allways right but its maybe better than unstable full 100%

Comment: I don't think that this chip is programmable at all but I am not an electronic expert.